# What is the procedure for buying a new car in the US (California)?

Tags: driving-license, social-security, vehicle-registration, car-insurance

I am a new student in the US. I want to buy a car in cash and found one in the Facebook market. But I don't know what are the afterwards steps?

1- Should I give all the money in cash to the seller and get the car and it's license (I think they call it pink paper)?

2- Should the seller come with me to the DMV office or any other place for paperwork, etc..? Or I must do it alone? (Meaning I only meet the seller before getting the car + it's license and it's not necessary to meet him/her again?)

3- Can I buy a car when I don't have a SSN/ITIN and also don't have a driver license?

4- When should I insure the car? Is it necessary? If so what is the minimum insurance that is mandatory to get?

5- If the seller writes lower price than what I paid him, or even writes the car is a gift to me, does this avoid tax or reduces it?

6- Are there any notes and tricks to consider that weren't in my previous questions?

Comment: It's called a pink slip. Once you buy the car it's yours. SSN/ITIN aren't important. But without a license, you can't legally drive the car at all - not even home after you've bought it. Also, you aren't going to get insurance without a drivers license, more specifically you won't be able to get named on the insurance as a *driver*. As far as I'm aware, you have no tax obligation. What the seller's is is irrelevant to you.

Comment: #5 is an attempt to limit the use tax assessed by DMV against the new owner when the change of registration is processed. DMV knows what vehicles are worth, and may disregard a bill of sale that DMV determines significantly undervalues the vehicle.

Comment: Pink Slip is slang, the DMV will call it a Vehicle Title. You definitely need insurance if the vehicle is going to be driven, which you can't do without a license (a driver insured on another vehicle may be able to drive it home for you, depending on the state you're in).

Comment: Whoops, I missed (California) in the title. Someone insured on another California vehicle can drive it home for you.

Comment: https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/vehicle-registration/new-registration/registering-a-vehicle-purchased-from-a-private-party/